# Huge PDF file size with PdfDocument on older Android

Tags: android, pdfdocument

I'm developing an Android app which generates PDF files. I'm using the Android PdfDocument api to do this. It works nice but I noticed that on older versions of Android (I tested 4.4 and 5.0) the size of the generated PDF is huge (about 80 MB for eight A4 pages). On Android 6.0.1 is about 2.2 MB. Does someone know what could be the issue here?

Thanks in advance.